# Structure classes in Android project with Retrofit2 and MVP

Tags: android, retrofit2, mvp

I have difficulties knowing how to structure the classes in an MVP Android project that uses retrofit2 for calls to the API. I need to make a login and a registration. The requests for both of these are different but the response is the same. How can I create&structure the model classes in the best way?

Answer (score 0):

As the matter of fact in `MVP` design pattern, there is a `View`(mostly a `fragment`), a presenter (has a duty to do logical things) and we have no an actual `model` there!

instead, there is a data part of your application that contains your database and internet connection that we can call it `model`.

I searched all the internet but I found the best example in below link:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/